# UWP WebView dosn't shows right click menu like Edge

Tags: webview, uwp, windows-10-universal, microsoft-edge, right-click

I am developing a UWP app, in which I use WebView control. This WebView control has text editing options like bold, italic.I am able to do those formatting by use of "execCommand". The right-click menu is working until I right click on any image. When I click any image from that point, I dont get any right click menu.

Here the steps I used

My webview code `<WebView x:Name="webView"></WebView>`

and in .cs file I have loaded a html string

```
string html = "<html><body text=\"black\" oncontextmenu=\"return true\" contenteditable=\"true\"></body></html>";
    public WebViewMenuTry()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        webView.NavigateToString(html);

    }
```

I set contenteditable=true , so I can paste contents from web.

1)I go to google chrome -> some random website -> select some text and image -> copy that content

2)came back to my app webview and press ctrl+v(paste)

3)text and image pasted without any issue.

4)if right click on text am getting menu for copy,paste,etc.

5)Now if I click or right click image, here after I will not get any right click menu for text as well for image.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `OnRightTapped` event on the webview ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I dont want handle right click event and to handle all actions . I just want to show default menu of the browser, so that it will take care of everything.

Comment: please see updated question.

Comment: I think you might find that the context menu you're referring to is provided by the browser i.e. Edge - not the WebView which in essence is just a part of the browser.